# Jasmine unit-testing on Titanium module

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, titanium, jasmine-node

I am currently trying jasmine-node to unit test my Titanium app. I am open to suggestions about switching to an other unit-testing framework if it can solve my problem but first, here is my question.

My installation of jasmine-node is working, I can perform very simple tests like this one :

```
var util = require('../app/controllers/utils.js');
describe("util test", function(){
  it('should compute the sum between 1 & 2', function(){
      var sum = util.computeSum(1, 2);
      expect(sum).toEqual(3);
  });
});
```

The above code tests the following function and works as expected.

```
exports.computeSum = function(a,b) {
    return a+b;
};
```

When I try to test some code which call the Ti module though, it fails, saying "Ti is not defined".

```
describe("Ti.UI",function(){
    it("create custom alert", function(){
        var view = util.displayCustomAlert("title", "message");
        should(view).not.be.null;
    });
});
```

Above function is tested by the following test :

```
exports.displayCustomAlert = function(customTitle, customMessage){
    return Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
        title:customTitle,
        message:customMessage
    });
};
```

How can I make jasmine-node work with Titanium ?

Comment: Hey did you ever got this figured out?

Comment: @user1554966 I don't recall I have. I was an intern at that time, without much time in my hands ; I think I just went on without testing Titanium components.
It was probably for the best though, you should really trust that the framework does its job and only test your custom code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [TiShadow](http://www.yydigital.com/blog/2013/2/14/Testing_Alloy_With_Jasmine_And_TiShadow) to run Jasmine tests or [TiO2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tio2) to run Mocha tests for Titanium apps.

Comment: I tried tio2 before jasmine, but I haven't been able to make it work. The simple `example` sample fails with errors without pointing at them, and I encounter [this issue](https://github.com/appcelerator/tio2/issues/14) by running on my project. I find the `read me` does not provide enough informations to make in work.
I will give TiShadow a try, thank you.